# What are the ranges of $x$ and $y$ in the Mercator projection?

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, 3d, projective-geometry, projection

> What are the ranges of $x$ and $y$ in the Mercator projection ?

I searched about it but I couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a mathematician, I'd say $\mathbb R$ for both $x$ and $y$.
The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) has many formulas describing this projection.  A Mercator map is periodic in the East/West direction, reflecting the fact that you can circle the earth as many times by going East or West.  That's what's behind the range $\mathbb R$ for $x$. The range $\mathbb R$ for $y$ is caused by the fact that the
North and South poles are not represented by a Mercator map, even though they are actual places on the Earth.

As a practical matter, one prints a bounded rectangular portion of a Mercator map to put in an atlas or to put on a wall map.  Such a truncated map will not include some neighborhood of the N and S poles, but (because of the E/W periodicity) show the full extent of the Equator, etc.  Often one sees (on American or European-made) Mercator maps two copies of the International Date Line; one can imagine maps printed in (say New Zeeland) as having two copies of the Greenwich meridian and one of the IDL.

Most software packages deliver an $x,y$ pair in the ranges $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ (or $-180\le x\le180$)  and $-\infty<y<\infty$. It is not clear to me from your comments how this matches up with what you want.

Comment: Of course nobody in their right mind makes world maps in Mercator projection (nor have they ever done; the supposed prevalence of Mercator world maps is a myth that started as a marketing campaign for Gall-Peters maps).

Comment: Could be, but "nobody in their right mind" is a dense subset of humanity.

Comment: Thank you but i don't want it for world map, I want it for my problem after that i want ti use a histogram so I need range of it.

Comment: Sorry: this wasn't clear to me from your problem statement.

Comment: I want to extract mercator projection for some points on the sphere then I want to show these with a 6 * 6 histogram that each bin shows number of points that mapped on that region